# SQL Function to count data

Tags: sql, function, count, phpmyadmin

Say I have 100 records in a certain column in a certain table.

All of these pieces of data in that column are random numbers from 1 to 10

What SQL function can I use to count the number that appears the most within those 100 records and it will display that number alone in the column?

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `mysql` (because of question tags):

```
  SELECT n
    FROM tablename
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this to get the count:

```
select count(*)
from t
group by col
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

This is MySQL syntax.  The `limit 1` is database-specific.  In SQL Server, for instance, it would be `select top 1`.

And this to get the number in the column:

```
select col
from t
group by col
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```